# How to ACTION_CALL within a Fragment using Tab & Swipe View in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, call, contacts, swipe

I have used stackoverflow for years when in college and now find myself asking my first question for my new job. I have done days of research (with at least 3 hours a day) and can't find a solution to my problem.
I'm sure it's something small and stupid but it illudes me!
I am trying to create an App that allows a user to tap a number/button to call a phone number relevant to the tab ontop.
So for TAB A they have a number A and the user can swipe right to TAB B for number B, etc.

Here's what I have so far in code:

MainActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:18004581552")));
```

Thanks for your help folks!
I appreciate all criticism and ideas!

OK sadly I'm having a terrible first experience of posting on stackoverfloor after spending a ridiculously long time now trying to format code for posting which it just won't allow me to do!!!

Here is the site I used to help me with the Swipe & Tab view.

http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tabs-and-swipe-views/?lang=en

I then added buttons to the xml layout files tab1, etc.
I am now trying to create an action on button press that will call a number.
I have no idea where I am going wrong. Stress to bits here.

Thanks,

Cormac

Comment: I have been able to do what I needed using the old activities way but really wanted to use the new Swipe & Tab view in the lastest API. Does anyone know or can point me in the right direction to find out how to place intents/activities like the one above into the Swipe & Tab view? I'm completely lost here! I searched online and did several tutorials but none seem to say basically where the code goes. Many Thanks for your time!